# Why did Apple refuse to refund a scam app?

Tags: mac-appstore

Apple website and staff refused twice to refund a Chinese video-editing app called 爱编辑. Then they won't accept request.

It's a scam app; numerous people commented in the app store about the scam to no avail. When you open this Mac app, there is only one button, which asks you to buy. Cancel doesn't work. It will ask buy again if you click the only existent button. The invoice shows I bought "forever membership", which actually means I can forever open this app, without any other membership service. By the way, the app can't function normally.

I reached for Apple's help immediately and multiple times to no avail. Can anyone explain Apple's policy?

So if you fall for a scam, Apple is not going to help you, just because money has already been paid to the app developer?

Here is the app, I hope no more people fall for it:
https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/%E7%88%B1%E7%BC%96%E8%BE%91-%E8%A7%86%E9%A2%91%E5%89%AA%E8%BE%91%E8%BD%AF%E4%BB%B6/id1533505801?l=en&mt=12
purchase time:2022/5/23, invoice: MQ5KGG1X8Y

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about why Apple chose to do something are off topic.

Comment: In your iOS settings the subscription tab should let you cancel any subscription you made through an app

Comment: @MicroMachine This is a once-and-for-all in-app purchase on mac.

Answer (score 2):

I have received refunds numerous times even for non-scam apps, usually because I bought it thinking it had a feature that it didn't.

You simply indicate either that it doesn't do what you expected or that you didn't mean to purchase it and they refund you.

If they deny it, it's probably because you request too many refunds.

Comment: This is the second app I paid for via appstore in-app purchase, and the first app I tried to refund.

Comment: Suppose a customer refunded too many times, but this app doesn't function normally. It crashes even for a short video, along with other malfunctions and devious behaviors as commented by so many other users. Apple just won't investigate, indulging scams in its store.

Comment: I have not seen any IAP refunded, ever. Outright app, yes

Comment: @bmike I trusted Apple's reputation because IAP is still conducted via Apple platform. If IAP cannot be refunded, unscrupulous developers will take full  advantage of this loophole .

Comment: It seems refunds are covered with few words at https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html - I didn’t say it was impossible, just I’ve never come across a case where someone got a refund on IAP.

Comment: @bmike Here's a refund of ESPN+ (subscription) issued the day after I subscribed and found it didn't contain content I expected https://i.imgur.com/K1LYbRd.png

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for confirming that refunds are possible @Ezekiel